# How do I add an audio book to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, windows, audiobook

I tried to add a `mp4` and `m4a` and `mp3` file to iTunes while viewing Audiobooks tab but it would not add the file. How do I add an audio book to my iPhone?

iTunes Version 12.10.1.4

Comment: You’re trying to do this from your Mac?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368705/how-can-i-listen-to-my-mp3-audiobooks-on-iphone

Comment: @ankii That is for iCloud, which I'm not using. They were able to import it into their iTunes to begin with, which is the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is your file type, audiobooks are usually MP3 files. MP3 files can only be used for audio, whereas MP4 files can store audio, video, still images, subtitles, and text. In technical terms, MP3 is an “audio coding” format while MP4 is a “digital multimedia container” format.

After changing file format, try importing into iTunes again and syncing the files to your iPhone [via USB](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/itunes/itns3081/windows).

Comment: No that's not it. I tried to add 3 different mp3 files, it paused for a second, but it didn't add them to the library either.

Comment: @Chloe see here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4527299

Comment: OMG they show up in 'Recently Added' playlist but not on the main 'Audiobooks' page. How retarded!

Comment: Not only that, but you can't drag it to the 'Recently Added' playlist. You have to drag it to the main 'Audiobooks' window then go to 'Recently Added' to actually see it. iTunes has so many usability problems!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in a link in a comment. This is the linked answer:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4527299

> Drag them to an empty playlist.  They may be adding but without labels.
>
> Will the files play in Quicktime Player?
>
> iTunes can be fussy about mp3 files.  They are not all the same and if they originated from some obscure PC encoder 15 years ago they may not be to modern iTunes' liking.  You can try:
>
> Topic : MP3 Scan+Repair - an ID3 tag evaluator for the Mac - http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2020936
>
> MP3 Scan+Repair (including sources): http://triq.net/mac/mp3-validator-mac-os-x

I had to drag them to the empty 'Audiobooks' window then go to 'Recently Added' to actually see them. Note you can't drag to 'Recently Added' playlist. It did add one `m4a` file but not another. I merely renamed the `m4a` files to `mp4` and then iTunes accepted them. You also have to go to the iPhone > Audiobooks and select 'Sync All Audiobooks' so it will actually copy them. It gave an error saying it could not copy some of the renamed `mp4` files, but it copied them anyways.